# Python - float warning, remove comma

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm new in Python,

I've this prices: 1,304.20 - 1,500.20 - 4.10 - 140.50

 
How remove comma?

```py
for open_price in df_open:
    if ',' in open_price:
        open_priceClean = open_price.replace(',', '')
        continue
    prices.append(float(open_priceClean))
```

I get back this warning:

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-67-80afd251c13d> in <module>()
     10 #Create the dependent data set 'y' as prices
     11 for open_price in df_open:
---> 12     if ',' in open_price:
     13         open_priceClean = open_price.replace(',', '')
     14         continue

TypeError: argument of type 'float' is not iterable
```

Comment: The prices seem to be stored in the dataframe as floats, not as strings. The floats don't inherently have commas in them.

Comment: `if ',' in open_price: open_price = open_price.replace(',', '')` and drop `continue`. You can reassign back to the same name. Then you just need `prices.append(float(open_price))` and it won't matter whether that value got transformed by your `if` check or not by the point it gets to the `append`

Comment: `df_open` is not defined. Please make a [mre], not necessarily with a dataframe, but a list would do for example.

Comment: If it _is_ a df then it probably would matter

Comment: `open_price` is not a `str`, it's actually a float

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
df_open = open("test.txt","r")
read_file = df_open.read().splitlines()
print (read_file)

for line in read_file:
    no_comas = (line.replace(",",""))
    print (no_comas)
```

Comment: This code has no use. Why would you just want to `print` an entire file to console?

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to show how to replace the coma. Maybe I'm missing something. I will review my answer